# Install Windows Server 2012 on the SSD from the HDD

Tags: windows-server-2012, ssd, windows-8.1

How can I install Windows Server 2012 on the SSD from the HDD, installed Windows 8.1? Laptop, which has no DVD or USB or network access.

Comment: @HBruijn but he says he has no network access, so PXE wont be a solution...

Comment: I have no idea what it is that you're asking.

Comment: @HBruijn oh sorry, I didn't notice the edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky thing to do. Basically, you can install windows from HDD, but it should be dedicated for the installer (marked as bootable just as you would do it with USB drive installation)

In your specific case (you have Windows `8.1` and without USB no real option to reformat drive), maybe you will try to install win2012 server over network with PXE if your BIOS supports that. Microsoft has a walktrough in their [library for Windows 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744541%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: While your answer may be helpful, providing links doesn't help future users as links may break in the future. Please try to summarize the steps in your answer.

Comment: does this include microsoft technet library? i don't want to make this answer become a PXE deployment howto, because that wasn't really the question, link is just for reference.

Comment: Technet is better as it's less likely to go defunct. Thanks for updating.